# How do I make text box autocomplete result selection navigate directly to record details?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I’m developing a CRUD project using ASP.NET MVC 4. There is a requirement to implement an autocomplete on search form text fields. I’ve been able to implement this using jQuery just fine using json. But this simply populates the text box with a search term when you select one of the autocomplete results. The functionality I need though is, when the user selects one of the autocomplete results (Which will display several fields of a record) the app goes directly to the details of that record instead of just putting the string value in the text box. How can this be done?

Below is my implementation of the autocomplete that simply places string values in text boxes if anyone happens to be looking for that kind of solution. I made a reusable partial view that I can plug into different views:

**Create javascript autocomplete with json in MVC**

Parameterized script in partial, re-usable cshtml class:

```
@{
  var boxId = ViewData["BoxId"];
  var controller = ViewData["Controller"];
  var action = ViewData["Action"];
  var paramName = ViewData["ActionParamName"];
  var dataField = ViewData["DataFieldName"];
  var data = "item." + dataField;
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#@(boxId)").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/@(controller)/@(action)",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { @paramName : request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: @data , value: @data };
                    }))

                }
            })
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
 })
</script>
```

**NOTE**:: The DataFieldName is the name of the accessor on the result object. In this case the APP_People_SEARCH_Result object has an accessor named FirstName

**ALSO**:: The ActionParamName must match the name of the argument in the action method in the controller class. In this case it’s firstName (i.e. string firstName)

Script on your View where it will be used:

```
@Html.Partial("_AutoComplete",  new ViewDataDictionary { new KeyValuePair<string, object("BoxId", "FirstNameTextBox"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Controller", "People"), new     KeyValuePair<string, object>("Action", "FirstNameAutoComplete"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>    ("ActionParamName", "firstName"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("DataFieldName", "FirstName") })

@using (Html.BeginForm("Select", "People", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "myclass", id = "" }))
{
  <p>First Name: @Html.TextBox("firstName", null, new { id = "FirstNameTextBox" })    </p>

  <p><input type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
}
```

Code in PeopleController.cs:

```
public JsonResult FirstNameAutoComplete(string firstName)
    {
        List<APP_People_SEARCH_Result> results = RunSearch(firstName, false);

        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

How it looks in source:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#FirstNameTextBox").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                url: "/People/FirstNameAutoComplete",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { firstName : request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.FirstName , value: item.FirstName };
                    }))

                }
            })
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
})
</script> 


<form action="/People/Select" class="myclass" method="post">    
    <p>First Name: <input id="FirstNameTextBox" name="firstName" type="text" value="" />    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
</form>
```

**Thanks to Silkster for the assistance.**

I was able to implement an almost reusable partial cshtml file:

```
@{
var boxId = ViewData["BoxId"];
var controller = ViewData["Controller"];
var action = ViewData["Action"];
var paramName = ViewData["ActionParamName"];
var idFieldID = ViewData["IdFieldID"];
var objectIdProperty = ViewData["ObjectId"];
var objectId = "item." + objectIdProperty;
//var recordResult = ViewData["RecordResult"];////doesnt work for label and value, have to hard-code it
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#@(boxId)").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/@(controller)/@(action)",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { @paramName : request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { 
                            label: item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName + ' ' + item.Department , 
                            value: item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName + ' ' + item.Department , 
                            recordKey : @objectId

                        };
                    }))

                }
            })
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {
                var elem = document.getElementById("@(idFieldID)");
                elem.value = ui.item.recordKey;

                $("form").submit();
            }
        }
    });
 })
</script>
```

In my view I add a hidden text box to store the ID of an objedct. I can almost totally paramaterize the partial (as seen above) except when I try to pass in a string that contains quotes, they don't translate in the produced script.

The View:

```
//Couldn't get the following to work
@*@Html.Partial("_PeopleAutoComplete",  new ViewDataDictionary { new KeyValuePair<string, object>("BoxId", "FirstNameTextBox"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Controller", "People"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Action", "FirstNameAutoComplete"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("ActionParamName", "firstName"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("IdFieldID", "people_ID"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("ObjectId", "People_ID")  , new KeyValuePair<string, object>("RecordResult", "item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName + ' ' + item.Department") })*@

//So I had to just use this. Values ended up being hard-coded
@Html.Partial("_PeopleAutoComplete",  new ViewDataDictionary { new KeyValuePair<string, object>("BoxId", "FirstNameTextBox"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Controller", "People"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Action", "FirstNameAutoComplete"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("ActionParamName", "firstName"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("IdFieldID", "people_ID"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("ObjectId", "People_ID")})

@Html.Partial("_PeopleAutoComplete",  new ViewDataDictionary { new KeyValuePair<string, object>("BoxId", "LastNameTextBox"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Controller", "People"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Action", "LastNameAutoComplete"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("ActionParamName", "lastName"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("IdFieldID", "people_ID"), new KeyValuePair<string, object>("ObjectId", "People_ID")})

@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResults", "People"))
{
  <p><input type="submit" value="Search" /></p>

  @Html.TextBox("people_ID", null, new {id = "people_ID", style = "display:none;" })

  <p>First Name: @Html.TextBox("firstName", null, new { id = "FirstNameTextBox" })</p>
  <p>Last Name: @Html.TextBox("lastName", null, new { id = "LastNameTextBox" })</p>
}
```

In my controller I first do a check to see if People_ID is null. If it's not I redirect to the details screen using the ID selected:

```
if (people_ID != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "People", new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = (int)people_ID }));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a select method in the autocomplete configuration.  See jQuery UI API reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select